# How to display configuration differences between two jenkins Jenkins builds?

Tags: jenkins, manifest, jenkins-pipeline

I want to display non-code differences between current build and the latest known successful build on Jenkins.

By non-code differences I mean things like:

- Environment variables (includes Jenkins parameters) (`set`), maybe with some filter
- Version of system tool packages (`rpm -qa | sort`)
- Versions of python packages installed (`pip freeze`)

While I know how to save and archive these files as part of the build, the only part that is not clear is how to generate the diff/change-report regarding differences found between current build and the last successful build.

Please note that I am looking for a pipeline compatible solution and ideally I would prefer to make this report easily accessible on Jenkins UI, like we currently have with SCM changelogs.

Or to rephrase this, how do I create build manifest and diff it against last known successful one? If anyone knows a standard manifest format that can easily be used to combine all these information it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you always ask the most baller questions, nice work. :)

we always try to push as many things into code as possible because of the same sort of lack of traceability you're describing with non-code configuration. we start with using Jenkinsfiles, so we capture a lot of the build configuration there (in a way that still shows changes in source control). for system tool packages, we get that into the app by using docker and by inheriting from a specific tag of the docker base image. so even if we want to change system packages or even the python version, for example, that would manifest as an update of the FROM line in the app's Dockerfile. Even environment variables can be micromanaged by docker, to address your other example. There's more detail about how we try to sidestep your question at https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/13/speaker-blog-rosetta-stone/.

there will always be things that are hard to capture as code, and builds will therefore still fail and be hard to debug occasionally, so i hope someone pipes up with a clean solution to your question.